# Lógica de uma implementação de rede neural

Tags: python, lógica, redes-neurais

Olá, Bom Dia

Fiz a implementação de uma rede, e nela se tem a seguinte matriz, onde f(x) é um vetor de entrada (matrix 1,139), a matriz phi que tem dimensão 1,20 (20 devido ao numero de sinais que usei pra treina-la) e w como sendo os pesos que são de dimensão 20,1

```
for k in range(0,20):                                           
    for item in range(0,139):
        substract += (s[0,item] - phi[0,k])            # phi = 20,20

    mod = np.linalg.norm(substract)

    substract = 0

    if(mod > 0):
        substract = (mod*mod)*math.log10(mod)
        phi_matrix_final.append(substract)
    else:
        phi_matrix_final.append(mod)

    mod = 0
    substract = 0
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sn = 20, devido ao numero de entradas pro treinamento

Problema dessa rede é que ela sempre retorna um valor muito próximo um do outro, já que as respostas deveriam ser entre 0 e 10

Observação: Uso a função r²log(r)

Comment: O que você faz com `phi_matrix_final` para que ela entre, na nova iteração, como `phi`? Porque eu acho que você não está reduzindo o erro de `phi`

Comment: aplico result = phi_matrix_final @ pesos

Answer (score 1):

Você deve ter uma só entrada na rede, com uma amostra de treinamento de 139 pontos, por isso que `phi` tem dimensão **1**x20 e os pesos, dimensão 20x1.

O que não está claro é por que você tem 139 saídas,

```
        substract += (s[0,item] - phi[0,k])          # phi = 20,20
                                                     # item varia de 0 a 139, ou seja, são 139 saídas?
```

O código, eu acho, deveria ser o seguinte, segundo sua equação,

```
x = [] # 139 amostras
s = [[]] # 139 amostras x 20 saídas esperadas

mod = 0.0 # forçando um erro em phi
modant = 1.0 # forçando um erro em phi

phi = np.zeros((1, 20)) # 1 entrada e 20 saídas

ctr = 0

eta = 0.3 # amortecimento

while abs(1 - mod/modant) > 0.01 and ctr < 10000:
    ctr += 1
    modant = mod

    for item in range(0,139):
        for k in range(0,20):                                       
            phi[0,k] += eta* (x[item] - s[item,k])

        mod = np.linalg.norm(s)
        if mod > 0:
            phi = (mod*mod*math.log10(mod)) @ phi
```

Comment: Olá, agradecido pela a resposta, porém ela retorna uma matriz 20,1. Saliento que após o for eu fazia

 phi_matrix_final = np.asmatrix(phi_matrix_final)  ### 
 phi_matrix_final = np.reshape(phi_matrix_final, (1,20))

Comment: Só um instante, vou editar.

Comment: Vou verificar, creio que não 139 saídas, pois x e s são vetores, e então treinei 20 kernels, ou seja a grosso modo, cada um dos 139 pontos menos o kernel s1, somados, e assim até o s20,

Comment: E eu acho que a minha implementação também está errada, porque você não está treinando com as saídas esperadas, que seria os `s`s. Para feed-forward, você também precisa das saídas.

Comment: Alterei para considerar as saídas.

Comment: Obrigado pela a resposta, mas ainda assim não foi suficiente pra resolver o problema

Comment: Qual é o problema agora?